# Priority Queue without built in Python functions

Tags: python-3.x, priority-queue

I am trying to setup a new server for a project in mechanical engineering. I plan on running a priority queue on the server for sorting what it will do next. Most mechanical engineers do not know how to code so I cannot find many people to help.

For reasons that are difficult to go into, I need to avoid most built in functions withing python. I want to limit myself to the following: pop, insert, if statements, and such. I have a simple one written, however, I need this in one function that computes whenever I input values. The current one essentially will sort at the end.

I want to make it into class PriorityQueue:
Then allow it to sort as items enter

```
class Queue:
  def __init__(self, iL=[]):
    self.aList = iL[:] 

  def enqueue(self, newItem:'item'):
    """put an item in back the queue"""
    # your code...
    self.aList.append(newItem)

  def dequeue(self)->'item': #return the item
    """remove an item from front of the queue, return the item"""
    # your code...
    return self.aList.pop(0)

  def empty(self):
    """Is the queue empty?"""
    # your code...
    return self.aList == []

  def __repr__(self): # for testing only
    return repr(self.aList)


# Use the Queue class as a Priority Queue by
# having a priority associated with each item, e.g.: 
# (2,'code') where item 'code' have priority 2
# (1, 'eat') this entry has a priority 1 and the item 'eat'
# (3, 'sleep') 'sleep' has priority 3
# Let's consider #1 to be the highest priority, be #1, then 2, then 3

# given this type of priority queue as input
# define a function to sort the queue,
# such that highest priority item (smallest number)will be served first
# return a sorted queue

def queueSorted(qu:Queue) -> Queue:
    # your code...
    # must use only those 3 queue functions
    # cannot use any python function for sorting
    qusorted = Queue()
    while not qu.empty():
      # find min, enqueue it into sorted
      qutemp = Queue()
      imin = qu.dequeue()
      while not qu.empty():
        itemp = qu.dequeue()
        if itemp < imin:
          itemp, imin = imin, itemp
        qutemp.enqueue(itemp)
      qusorted.enqueue(imin)
      # do rest
      qu = qutemp
    return qusorted
```

Comment: 'limit myself to the following: pop, insert, if statements, *and such*' - that seems a little too broad to be useful. What are the constraints, exactly?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. First, if you're trying to maintain a sorted list, then a priority queue isn't really what you want. You say that you want to return a sorted queue. Do you really want a sorted queue, or do you just want something that, when asked for the next item, will always return the one with the highest priority?

Comment: This is for a program I am writing that will run a CNC drill system, so it will process each of the items as a queue, however some items will need to be skipped in the priority list. Literally you can ignore the pre written code. I just need some sort of priority queue. Ik the function in the code says sorted queue, because that is all I have found on the internet on doing it from scratch after several hours. I did find a linked list but not necessarily trying to do a linked list.